# Can't dispatch DDM chunk 52454151: no handler defined error

Tags: android

This code is not work properly.

```
  Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start);
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this,Lession1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Lession1.this,TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Error:** Can't dispatch DDM chunk 52454151: no handler defined error

Comment: Please post your logcat and change the question's name according to the real exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are created double application and it can not calling each other.
if you want to create activity 1 to 2 you have to user onResume() method for exit that activity.